# how to setup RouteConfig in Asp.net MVC for angular js

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am setting up angular routing for my asp.net mvc app, what I want is to redirect all the request for localhost/users/ to index page so that I can use angular's client side route except localhost/users/add, which I will use .Net's route.
How to set it up RouteConfig?

Here is my current setting and I don't believe it's working

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "UsersCatchAllRoute",
            url: "Users/{action}",
            defaults: new
            {
                controller = "Users",
                action = "Index",
                id = UrlParameter.Optional
            },
            constraints: new { action = @"(?-i)add" }
```

Answer (score 0):

On our current project we use the following code. It means that anything in /app/ will be ignored and therefore handled by the angular routing. Hopefully even if this isn't exactly the code you need it will help you get there.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("app/{*.}");

var default_route = new {
    controller = "Home",
    action = "Index",
    id = UrlParameter.Optional
};

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: default_route
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "AngularApp",
    url: @"app/",
    defaults: default_route
);
```

Comment: That's great, does that mean all your angular route start with /app/ ?

Comment: it does yes. This is ok for us. We will change it to `/` once we have recoded all of our MVC.net into Angular.